# Trying to automate file move on subdirectory change with Watchman(or any other tool that can do this)

Tags: automation, watchman

Currently while working with watchman, I am trying to watch a directory, and when any new directory is created in that directory, that contains a file with the wildcard `*.m*`, it would start a trigger. However this is not working as expected.

I am watching the directory /media with the following:

`watchman watch /media`

My current trigger is set as follows:

```
[
  "trigger",
  "/media",
  {
    "name": "movieReady",
    "expression": [
      "anyof",
      ["match", "**/*.m*", "basename"]
    ],
    "command": ["python", "/scripts/dhooks/files/downloader.py"]
  }
]
```

So the goal is when any new media file hits `/media/NewDirectory/mediafile.mkv`
that it triggers that downloader.py, but watchman is not currently setting the trigger as it should when I move a folder with a test file to /media/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was to use `["match", "*", "basename"]` instead of `["match", "**/*.m*", "basename"]`, and then just filter in the pyhon script for what I need.